# Switching 15V, 1.5A AC with SSR

Tags: solid-state-relay

I need to switch 15V, 1.5A AC into a resistive load with a 5V control signal. Will this SSR work?
http://cpc.farnell.com/crydom/aso242/ssr-2a/dp/SW03811

To be specific, I do not understand the term 'minimum operating voltage: 24Vrms'.

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet yet?

Comment: Yes. But my query is fundamental in nature since I do not understand 'minimum operating voltage' with respect to the output side of an SSR. This link http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Other%20Related%20Documents/Omron%20Other%20Doc/SSR%20Design%20Considerations.pdf provides a glossary of terms with respect to SSR, but it doesn't clear my query. Datasheet of the SSR: http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/a_so.pdf I have gone through it also.

Comment: I bring it up because the datasheet disagrees with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your operating voltage is 15Vrms then it will work according to the datasheet.

[image: datasheet]

In the datasheet, it's written that operating voltage is in the range 12Vrms to 280Vrms. It might have been a typo on that webpage (24Vrms). However make sure that 15V is **rms** and **not peak to peak**.

Answer (score 0):

some SSRs are triac-based and these require a minumum voltage and current to operate correctly

for low voltages like 15V you want a dual MOSFET based SSR

eg. this one. http://uk.farnell.com/panasonic-ew/aqv252g2sx/relay-solid-state-spst-no-3a-10ma/dp/2302216